# What happens when you mix AgClO4 and CaBr2?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

> Predict if a reaction will occur when silver perchlorate and calcium bromide are mixed. If a precipitation reaction occurs, complete the reaction and include the physical states of the products, and balance the equation. If no reaction occurs, explain why.

I think a reaction does occur, but I'm not positive. Silver perchlorate and calcium bromide would give silver bromide and calcium perchlorate:

$$\ce{2 AgClO4 + CaBr2 = 2 AgBr + Ca(ClO4)2}$$

I'm unsure about the physical state of the products.

Comment: This is a [homework](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/141/7448) question. We have a policy which states that ‎you should show your thoughts and/or efforts into solving the problem. It'll make us certain that ‎we aren't doing your homework for you. Otherwise, this question may get closed.‎ Please [edit] in your full reasoning or thoughts on this.

Comment: You propose a double displacement reaction.  In water solution you can get that if there is something insoluble.  Is there such a thing here?  What is it?

Comment: Thank you for editing the question. Assuming the reaction takes place in aqueous media, you should've checked the solubility of the reactants in water first, and if they do dissolve in water, then the reaction takes place. Same for the products to determine their physical states. I retracted my close-vote and upvoted the question.

Answer (score 2):

You have already figured out the common concept:

- in water salts may dissolve
- if they do, they will dissociate into their ions
- the ions may recombine and form insoluble products which then precipitate from the solution

Good!

How to figure out whats happens for a particular combination of salts (such as silver chlorate and calcium bromide)?

1. Look up the solubilities of the starting materials and the possible products. If you don't have solubility tables in your study materials, wikipedia is ok.
2. If you run into values for a **solubility product** ($K_{sp}$) rather than a solubility given in grammes per 100 mL, you should be on red alert!

In the case of $\ce{AgBr}$, you should find a value around $5\cdot10^{-13}$. Please read about the **solubility product** to figure out what it means!

If you figure out that it indicates remarkably low remaining concentrations for a particular combination of ions in solutions (while the majority of your material has precipitated) you're on the right track!

In such cases, you might then go into details in your reaction equation:

$$\ce{2AX(s) + BY2(s) ->[H2O] B^{2+}(aq) + 2 X-(aq) + 2AY v}$$